# Convert Hive Row Object to Integer Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the output of a hive column into key value pair.

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
id1 = sqlContext.sql("select instance_id from temp_table")
pairs1 = id1.map(lambda s: (int(s), 'Configuration'))
```

I am getting the below error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Row'
```

I am not sure how to typecast the Hive Row object into a integer so that I can apply the map function to that

For example, the id1 is a dataframe and when I apply collect() to that it returns

```
[Row(_c0=12616821)]
```

I need the extract the value from the Row Object. Please let me know if any solution related to this problem

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a way to get the integer value from the Row Object. Initially I thought of applying typecast and converting it into int and few other methods.But it seems we can get the value by applying the index as simple as that

```
>> id1 = sqlContext.sql("select int(id) as id  from temp_table limit 1")
>> temp = df1.select('id').collect()

>> temp
[Row(id = 9331413)]

>> temp[0][0]
9331413
```